# Get javadoc version for a class?

Tags: java, version

I use the javadoc *@version* tag in my classes, however I am not sure how to **get** the version in the class itself. Let's look at an example...

```
/**
 * @version 1.0a
 * @author Redandwhite
 */
public class JClass extends JFrame implements ActionListener, KeyListener {
    String version = ...
}
```

Is there a method/class that can retrieve the version? Ideally, it's as simple as an API call which returns a simple String.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The javadoc comments are not included in the generated byte code in any form, so there is no way to access the value of the @version tag from Java code (unless you parse the source code of course). There might be a version annotation that can be used to specify the class version instead of or in addition to the javadoc @version tag, and this annotation would be accessible via the Java reflection API (i.e. `Class.getAnnotations()`).

Comment: One little caveat: The `@deprecated` JavaDoc tag (not to be confused with the annotation called `@Deprecated`)  is actually represented in the class file (only its existence, not the optional comment). That's the only place where the content of a comment influences the result of the compilation in Java.

Comment: that is indeed unfortunate. Thanks for the helpful info

Answer (score 1):

As it's already been noted, it's not possible to get to that information.

An alternative solution is to read the [`Implementation-Version`/`Specification-Version` property of the package](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html).

That value can be defined in the `MANIFEST.MF` file of a jar file. If it is defined, then it can be queried for every package that's contained in that jar file.

So if you have a class `org.example.MyClass` and the jar it comes in has the relevant entries in the `MANIFEST.MF` file, then you can get the version like this:

```
Class<?> clazz = org.example.MyClass.class
Package pkg = clazz.getPackage();
String version = pkg.getImplementationVersion();
```

Comment: this seems in line with what i'm looking for.. any idea how to set the VERSION value for the MANIFEST.MF file from within Netbeans?